# Proper use cases for Android ActivityManager.isUserAMonkey()?

Tags: java, android

I was looking at the new APIs introduced in Android 2.2. While looking at the ActivityManager class I came across the following method:

> `public static boolean isUserAMonkey()`
>
> Used to determine whether the user making this call is subject to teleportations.
>
> Returns whether the user making this call is a monkey.

How and when should this be used?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strange function in ActivityManager: isUserAMonkey. What does this mean, what is its use?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7792123/strange-function-in-activitymanager-isuseramonkey-what-does-this-mean-what-is)

Answer (score 4):

as per android docs

```
Returns "true" if the user interface is currently being messed with by a monkey.
```

to know the application is testing using [monkey](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/monkey.html) or not

Answer (score 1):

well if you do some automatic testing there will be test users. this method checks if the current user is such a test user.

about how to use it there are already a lot of topics, see:
[clickMe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9869488/what-is-the-use-of-activitymanager-isuseramonkey-method)